# Crear servicio web soap y alojarlo en servidor

Tags: php, java, eclipse, soap, tomcat

Necesito desarrollar un web service con soap en eclipse. Estoy buscando en la web pero no encuentro la información que necesito al respecto.
He desarrollado un servicio web con anotaciones y lo ejecuto en eclipse, y mediante un endpoint puedo acceder al wsdl en el naavegador. Pero lo que yo quiero es tener ese servicio alojado en un servidor y que pueda realizar peticiones desde un cliente php, sin tener abierto el eclipse.
¿Alguien me puede indicar como hacerlo o algún manual donde pueda ver como se hace?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo

Comment: La pregunta es definitivamente demasiado amplia, pero lo que necesitas es un servidor web Java (Tomcat, TomEE, Glassfish, Wildfly....). De hecho lo que hará Eclipse es lanzar uno de esos por detrás, aunque lo integre con el IDE.

Comment: Puedes crear tu servicio web escribiendo tu propio código PHP y alojarlo en cualquier servidor que tenga habilitado SOAP. Mira este ejemplo: https://academy.leewayweb.com/como-exponer-un-webservice-soap-con-php/

Comment: Yo ya he creado el servicio web con java y eclipse. Puedo acceder al wsdl desde el navegador a traves de la dirección que puse en el endpoint. Pero lo que quiero, es poder acceder al wsdl sin tener abierto eclipse. ¿Cómo lo consigo?

Comment: Este es el código donde publico el servicio, esta clase la ejecuto como una aplicación java normal, y luego pongo esa dirección en el navegador y accedo al wsdl. Lo que quiero es alojarlo en tomcat y que pueda acceder desde el navegador sin eclipse. Necesito ayuda por favor                                                                                          
public class PublishPeliculaService {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Endpoint.publish("http://localhost/academia/peliculas", new PeliculaDAO());

 }

}

Comment: Al final he solucionado el problema sin utilizar ningún server. Como el propio servicio lo publica en una especie de servidor virtual sin necesidad de tomcat, lo que he hecho es crearme un jar del proyecto y ejecutarlo desde una consola. En ese momento ya tengo disponible el wsdl y puedo realizar peticiones al servicio.